# Is there any way to tell if a discord.Message is replying to another message?

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I am developing a discord bot (nothing serious, just something fun to learn the language a bit) and we recently ran out of pins in General, so I thought: "why not make a %pin command?"

The command itself works nicely, writing the pinned message in a .json file, however, it pins the last message that was sent in the chat, (before the command obviously) and I want to make it so it pins the message that the user is replying to, not the one before the command. Is there any way to get the message that the user is replying to?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: provide code or else we don't know what you did wrong

Comment: @WasiMaster I didn't do anything wrong, I'm just asking a question (last line)

Comment: Oh oops, I misread, sorry. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the message the user replied to by using [`Message.reference`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Message.reference)

```py
@bot.command()
async def pin(ctx):
    await ctx.message.reference.resolved.pin()
```

Here [`ctx.message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.message) is the original message that invoked the command, we get the replied message using [`.reference`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Message.reference) then we use [`.resolved`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.MessageReference.resolved) to actually get the [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Message) object of the replied message. then we pin it using [`.pin()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#discord.Message.pin).

*Note*: the await is there for the `pin()` only, nothing else requires await

Comment: I guess I should've read the docs better because it's literally there... anyways I don't need the ```.pin()``` part because I'm "pinning" it in the .json file, I only need the ```Message```. Thanks a bunch!